# Wkhtmltopdf rendering wrong due to javascript problem

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, wkhtmltopdf

I am working in a card game and I decided to create a python script to speed up the prototyping. This is what the script does:

1. It fills an HTML template using jinja.
2. It renders the HTML page with wkhtmltopdf and crop the image with scikitimage.
3. It creates a PDF with 9 cards per page with FPDF.

All the code can be found here: [card-generator](https://github.com/edoelas/card-generator).

I also have added some javascript to decrease the font size when titles are too long. This javascript code can be found in `card-generator/assets/script.js`. What this code does is take the div with `id='name'` and decrease the font size until its size plus the margins are smaller than the father size.

The problem is that although this javascript works perfectly when opened from the browser, it does not behave as expected when rendered with wkhtmltopdf. As far as I know wkhtmltopdf uses qute browser to render the images and when opened with qute browser the cards look fine. This is how the file `card-generator/html_out/Too looong title.html` looks when opened with qute browser:

[image: qute browser render]

This is the same html opend with qute browser but with the while loop that takes care of the resizing commented in `card-generator/assets/script.js`:

[image]

This is how the file `card-generator/png_out/Too looong title_1.png` looks. This png is the resoult of rendering the previous html:

[image: wkhtmltopdf render]

To replicate the problem just open the python notebook (.ipynb) and execute the cells.

As you can see the title was not resized. I have discovered that the problem is that the title's div does not grow with the text, as seen in the last image. The text overflows, so when in the JS I get the dimension with `element.offsetWidth` it does not return the size of the text but the size of the div, that fits perfectly. This results in not resizing the font.

I have seen other wkhtmltopdf users complaining about similar isues but I have tried everything and nothing seems to solve this isue. Other options to render the HTML to a PNG are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Using pyppeteer instead of wkhtmltopdf solves the problem.